# How does Nginx Ingress handle an incoming WebSocket Connection over HTTPS (wss:...) when routing to backend over HTTP? (ws:...)?

Tags: nginx, websocket, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using Nginx Ingress to kubernetes services:

Does Nginx transform the request from wss:... to a ws:... ?
OR
Does Nginx require the back end to also have HTTPS enabled? Making it a simpler wss:... to wss:...
If this is the case, then would a self signed cert be OK on the back-end? and how would I configure the proxy to connect to that back-end successfully?

I currently have Web-sockets working over HTTP to the back-end (ws:... to ws:...) and I don't really know how to go the next level and get this working over HTTPS! I guess that's the main question here.

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: xxxx-virtual-server
  namespace: {{ .Values.tenantName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "xxxx.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
  host:  {{ .Values.tenantName }}.x.cloud
  tls:
    secret: aks-ingress-tls
  upstreams:
  - name: aaa-upstream
    service: aaa-service
    port: 5000
  - name: bbb-upstream-socket
    service: bbb-service-socket
    port: 80
  routes:  
  - path: /
    matches:
    - conditions:
      - header: Upgrade
        value: websocket
      action:
        pass: bbb-upstream-socket 
    action:
      pass: aaa-upstream
```

Comment: Could you share your current config/yaml? Is there any error you see when trying this out?

Comment: works ok over http... with the socket link containing ws:...   it's only when I go to https and change the link to wss:... that the negotiation fails.  So I assume the yaml is ok,... but I do get a "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid." error,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this working, so for anyone else out there who are wondering the same thing, here is what I found.

I'm using Nginx Ingress to kubernetes services:

Does Nginx transform the request from wss:... to a ws:... Yes it can :-)

Does Nginx require the back end to also have HTTPS enabled: No it doesn't.

Basically we setup the socket to listen on the url "/ws/".

Connect from browser using URL like:

wss://test.cytrack.cloud/ws/

Then using Nginx Ingress Virtual Server Custom Resource we add:

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: abc-virtual-server
  namespace: abcd
spec:
  host:  abcde
  tls:
    secret: aks-ingress-tls
  upstreams:
  - name: abc-upstream-socket
    service: abc-service-socket
    port: 80
    read-timeout: 300s
    send-timeout: 300s
  - path: /ws/
    action:
      pass: abc-upstream-socket
```